# How to use the dataset comes from pytorch random_split()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm new to pyTorch and this is my first project. I need to split the dataset and feed the training dataset to model. **The training dataset must be splitted in to features and labels (which I failed to do that)**.  Here is what I have tried so far, however, I don't know how to feed the dataset obtained from `random_split()` to model.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.optim import SGD
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from dataset import DataSet


class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    input_dim = 10
    hidden_dim = 4
    output_dim = 1

    def __init__(self, dataset):
        super().__init__()

        self.layers = [
            nn.Linear(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim),
            nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.output_dim)
        ]
        self.train_dataset = dataset["train_dataset"]
        self.test_dataset = dataset["test_dataset"]
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(self.layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = nn.functional.rrelu(layer(x))


dataset = DataSet()
model = NeuralNetwork(dataset)
model(dataset["train_dataset"])
```

and this is `dataset.py`

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader


class DataSet:
    divide_rate = 0.8
    file = './pima-indians-diabetes.csv'

    def __init__(self):
        data_set = pd.read_csv(self.file)
        train_size = int(self.divide_rate * len(data_set))
        test_size = len(data_set) - train_size
        self.train_dataset, self.test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(data_set, [train_size, test_size])
        self.train_dataset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(self.train_dataset, shuffle=True)
        self.test_dataset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(self.test_dataset, shuffle=True)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)
```

The error is

> TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not DataLoader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem lies with your class Dataset, please replace it with following function,

```
def load_data(test_split, batch_size):
"""Loads the data"""
sonar_dataset = SonarDataset('./sonar.all-data')
# Create indices for the split
dataset_size = len(sonar_dataset)
test_size = int(test_split * dataset_size)
train_size = dataset_size - test_size

train_dataset, test_dataset = random_split(sonar_dataset,
                                           [train_size, test_size])

train_loader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset.dataset,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(
    test_dataset.dataset,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True)

return train_loader, test_loader
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from `model(dataset["train_dataset"])`. That lines takes the DataLoader for the training data and passes it to the model as a Tensor to execute the model on. Instead, to train a model, you need to create an optimization loop that iterates over the DataLoader like this:

```
dataset = DataSet()
model = NeuralNetwork() # Don't pass the dataset to your models

loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.05)

for X, y in dataset['train_dataset']:
    pred = model(X)
    loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

    # Backpropagation
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if batch % 100 == 0:
        loss, current = loss.item(), (batch + 1) * len(X)
        print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
```

But you probably want to test using your test DataLoader during your training process as well. DataLoaders are iterable so it looks similar the above for the training data. But you have to be careful to turn off the gradients. Look at the below link for more details:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/optimization_tutorial.html#full-implementation

Comment: The csv file has columns `pregnancy,plasma,blood_pressure,skin_fold,serum_insulin,body_mass,pedigree,age,class`.  when I write `for pregnancy in dataset['train_dataset']:` it reports error

Comment: This is the error `raise KeyError(key) from err`

Comment: @MamaD Can you edit your answer at the bottom with the new code? It does look like you are using it wrong still. Look at my example above. I did `for X, y in dataset['train_dataset']:`. The csv columns you mentioned are the columns of the resulting `X` in the above loop. But `X` is a pytorch Tensor type, not Pandas dataframe. So don't try to query `X` like Pandas. In fact, you should not need to touch the columns of the Tensors while training, especially if you're still learning.